# How to create Calendar control using jquery in MVC3 aspx view engine

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on an ASP.Net MVC3 project.  I am currently developing a page that has one date field and I want to use the date time jQuery picker control.

Comment: A simple google for "jQuery Datepicker" would have avoided you asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

How about composing a [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/download) download with just the datepicker?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a lasting solution, then there are a number of ways you can go about doing this.  The one I prefer (and is shown on Pluralsight):

Create an Editor Template for the date time data type (~/View/Shared/Editor Templates):

```
@model System.DateTime

@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, new { data_datepicker = true })
```

Then in the View/Layout have the jQuery and jQuery UI called before running the following wire up:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(":input[data-datepicker]").datepicker();
})
```

The benefit of this approach, means that every time you have a Date Time field on the page, it will 'just work' as the wire up jQuery finds all the input elments on the page that have the "data-datepicker" attribute added to them (you can make the data- attribute whatever you like so long as they match in the editor and the wire up jQuery).